# Matrix multiplication - "ValueError: matrices are not aligned". Even with same shapes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two dataframes (exactly the same number of rows and columns). When I perform the following matrix operation: `(A).T.dot(Dn).div(Dn.sum())`, It works for the first matrix (D1) but for the second(D2), I'm getting the error "ValueError: matrices are not aligned".

D1 and D2 are both dataframes and have exactly the same shape, the same indexes and the same columns. However, the only difference between them is the following:

D1

```
{dtype('float64'): Index(['10701', '10702', '10703', '10704', '10705', '10706', '10707', '10708',
        '10709', '10710',
        ...
        '32105', '32106', '32107', '32201', '32202', '32203', '32204', '42001',
        '42002', '42003'],
       dtype='object', length=221)}
```

D2

```
{dtype('int64'): Int64Index([31409], dtype='int64'),
 dtype('float64'): Int64Index([10701, 10702, 10703, 10704, 10705, 10706, 10707, 10708, 10709,
             10710,
             ...
             32105, 32106, 32107, 32201, 32202, 32203, 32204, 42001, 42002,
             42003],
            dtype='int64', length=220)}
```

Any guidance?

Comment: I'm not sure they do have exactly the same shape. `D2` is of length 220 and `D1` is of length 221.

Comment: That's weird... when I do: D1.shape and D2.shape I get (221, 221) in both cases.

Comment: How do you define D1 and D2?